# Infopath repeating section drop down duplicate value check

Tags: infopath2010

I have drop down list on repeating section which is populated with "Languages" list from XML file. I would like to restrict duplicate language selection in the drop down but it's not working.

Here is the interface,

[image]

Repeating section is bind with "Questions" section and drop down field is bind with "Label1"

[image]

Here is data source of drop down list,

[image]

I tried adding following formula on "result" field to get the count of duplicate selection but it is returning 0 all the time,

```
count(Label1[text() = preceding-sibling::*/../Questions/Question/Label1/text()]) + count(Label1[text() = following-sibling::*/../Questions/Question/Label1/text()])
```

Any help will be must appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and see the following step its works properly for `Enter choices manually` choice in drop down box
Steps

1.) Add a validation rule.

2.) In condition puts following

```
  "Dropdown name"  is equal to  "preceding::Dropdown name" or
  "Dropdown name"  is equal to  "following::Dropdown name"
```

3.) Give the screen tips.

Note: please type

`preceding::Dropdown name` and `following::Dropdown name` in `Use a formula` area

Comment: k dude carry on  @Rishi

Comment: Another condition I am trying almost like above but instead of one condition there will be two. But it's not working.Condition is there are two drop down lists and both are drop down values should be unique across. For example, If in first row Drop down1= A and Drop down2=B then next row it shouldn't allow A and B selection again. 

I tried adding condition on Drop Down 2 like,

Drop Down1 is equal to preceding::Drop Down1 or
Drop Down1 is equal to following::Drop Down1  and
Drop Down2 is equal to preceding::Drop Down2 or
Drop Down2 is equal to following::Drop Down2

@SAT

Comment: I cannot understand clearly but upto my knowledge you separate the Drop Down1 is equal to preceding::Drop Down1 or Drop Down1 is equal to following::Drop Down1 in one filter condition and Add another filter condition for Drop Down1 is equal to following::Drop Down1 and Drop Down2 is equal to preceding::Drop Down2 or Drop Down2 is equal to following::Drop Down2 @Rishi